# How do I install node packages on sublime text

Tags: javascript, npm

I was just wondering if it’s possible to install node packages from sublime instead of the command line. And if it is how do I go about it

I don’t mean package control, I mean installing npm packages e.g the twilio  helper library.

Comment: If sublime lets you open a terminal, then you can do it "from sublime". You will still need to type the command into a terminal window though.

Comment: There’s no terminal on sublime that’s why I had to use the command line, I was just wondering if there was a much more efficient way to do it

Answer (score -1):

Yes,its possible,
First you need to install the **sublime package control**.
Follow the following steps to install the package controller:-

1. Open sublime text.
2. Click on the **tools** bar.
3. Select the **Command Palette** option.
4. Type the following: **Install Package Control**
5. Once the search result appears click on it or hit enter. Once the package control is installed, open the install Packages via the package control by performing the following steps.
6. Open sublime text again.
7. Click on the **tools** bar.
8. Select **Command Palette**.
9. Type **Package Control: Install Package** and hit enter.  Then a menu will appear showing along with search box different packages, search what you want and hit enter to install it. In your case you wanted to install node, you can do so by typing it in the search box. eg. `Nodejs`.

Comment: No. Package Control is for managing Sublime Text plugins, not Node packages. Installing *nodejs* that way will install a package with "nodejs snippets and bindings for Sublime Text 3" and not Node.js itself.

Comment: I guess that's what he wanted as an answer!

Comment: No I want to install node packages, like helper packages and things like that